# Failed Dependencies for Sphinx Search install

Tags: linux, mysql, sphinx

Im Running Centos 5.6 im trying to install Sphinx Search but keep getting errors with missing dependencies.
Im running

```
sudo rpm -Uvh sphinx-2.0.2-1.el5.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    libexpat.so.0()(64bit) is needed by sphinx-2.0.2-1.rhel5.x86_64
    libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) is needed by sphinx-2.0.2-1.rhel5.x86_64
    libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) is needed by sphinx-2.0.2-> 1.rhel5.x86_64
```

I have mysql installed when I run

```
yum install mysqlclient
No package mysqlclient available.
```

I checked the sphinx forum and nobody has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
yum install mysql expat
```

This will install MySQL client programs, its shared libraries and also `expat` which you also seem to be missing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that. I get this message               `Setting up Install Process
Package mysql-5.1.52-1.6.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package expat-2.0.1-9.1.8.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

Comment: @CraigH That is not CentOS 5.anything. I think your question needs to be changed, if you are really using Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Installing needed packages solves the issue. Here, for example, a similar situation: http://snippetsofcode.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/how-to-fix-failed-dependencies-when-installing-rpm-sphinx-search-on-centos/

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have package mysql-devel installed.